# Rewriting code with many loops in Java

Tags: java, loops

Can someone tell me if the following crazy loop structure can be rewritten in a much nicer way? Right now it does everything I want it to.

```
    // xi and yi stand for x and y axis input index
    for (int xi = 0; xi < this.inputNumberOfColumnsAlongXAxis; xi++)
    {
        for (int yi = 0; yi < this.inputNumberOfColumnsAlongYAxis; yi++)
        {
            InputCell inputCell = new InputCell(xi, yi);
            Synapse synapse = new Synapse(inputCell);
            // add (inputDataScaleReductionOnXAxis * inputDataScaleReductionOnYAxis)
            // number of synapses to a proximalSegment.
            for (int x = 0; x < this.numberOfColumnsAlongXAxis; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < this.numberOfColumnsAlongYAxis; y++)
                {
                    int inputX =
                        (int)Math.round(x * inputDataScaleReductionOnXAxis);
                    int inputY =
                        (int)Math.round(y * inputDataScaleReductionOnYAxis);
                    this.columns[(y * this.numberOfColumnsAlongXAxis) + x] =
                        new Column(this, inputX, inputY, x, y);

                    // only add the square of synapses directly under the proximal segment
                    while (xi < this.inputDataScaleReductionOnXAxis * (x + 1))
                    {
                        while (yi < this.inputDataScaleReductionOnYAxis * (y + 1))
                        {
                            this.getColumn(x, y).getProximalSegment().addSynapse(synapse);
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Looks like in every loop you are dealing with a different collection. Can you provide a brief description, about your program?

Comment: I suppose then the first question that I'd ask is, "What is your intention with these loops?"  It's tough to conjecture that from first glance..

Comment: I see a bunch of high-brow naysayers down-voting my rule, but no one seems willing to put pen to paper will any real suggestions.  All talk, no walk.

Comment: Often when you have heavily nested code that does what you want, you can simply extract some of the inner loops as methods. That gives you the chance to briefly describe what they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a 2-D data structure of cells and an `O(N^3)` initialization process where the `N` is the number of cells.  That looks kind of expensive ... but that is only a significant issue if N is very large or the process is done frequently.

Anyway, I cannot see anything in the code that can obviously be simplified ... assuming that the current algorithm reflects the requirements.  It would appear that the 6 levels of looping are inherent in the problem.  Some computations are like that.

The only possibility I can see is that `N` synapses with `O(N^2)` connections (I think that is what you are doing) ... is somehow unrealistic.  In other words, we can only suggest non-trivial improvements if we actually understand the problem you are trying to solve with this code.

---

Note that I am not saying *"As a rule, if something that complex works, don't mess with it."*.  What I'm saying is that:

- some things inherently cannot be improved ...  and this *looks like* one such thing, and
- maybe it doesn't matter anyway; e.g. if this code is just executed once ...

*"If it works don't mess with it"* is ... IMO ... a poor excuse for brushing problems under the carpet without giving them proper thought.

And *"Don't bother trying to optimize because usually the extra time and effort produces nothing ..."* is simply another formulation of the same excuse.  To me, it says *"I'm so good that my initial code cannot be improved on"* or *"I'm so bad that I cannot ever find decent optimizations"* or *"Too bad ... the customer shouldn't be expecting decent performance anyway"*.

Note that this is significantly different from the standard (and valid) advice which is ... *"Profile before you optimize"*.

Comment: All talk.  Show him the working code.

Comment: @ChrisGerken - he already has working code.  I'm saying that I don't think he can improve it.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the size of your inputs. The growth rate of these nested loops is not good. I.e., as the size of the inputs grows, the time it takes to run you algorithm will grow much faster, exponentially faster. But if you know your inputs will always be small, then it is fine as it is.